# Images not aligning properly to text when browser size changes - sometimes disappearing off the screen

Tags: html, css

The current issue I have is when I resize my browser window, bigger especially, the images I've added in disappear off the screen, or overlap with the text above it.

I've tried aligning it differently, but again, I find that either it's not worked, or it'll disappear off the page.  Potentially because my text and my image aren't talking to one another, and are just sitting on the page together, but I'm not sure how to fix this so any suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated.

Also had a little trouble resizing my `button`, I've tried targeting the height/width in both `HTML` and `CSS`, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

**Current issue**: the button's disappeared off the page completely, and the image has overlapped the text.

[Current Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUXGI.png)

Expected outcome: Ideally would look something like below, but button would be smaller, higher etc.  Text would ideally be more bulky in a paragraph, so it's not just 1 line that runs across the entire page, but maybe 3 or 4 lines centered.

[Expected Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ6nn.png)

Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <head>
        <title>The Impossible Journey</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="assets/images/buttons/website_browser_icon.png">
        <style>

             @font-face{
                font-family:myFirstFont; 
                src: url('assets/fonts/makoa.ttf');

            }

            @font-face{
                font-family:mySecondFont; 
                src: url('assets/fonts/simplicity.otf');
            }

            .div1 {
                font-family: myFirstFont;
                font-size: 10em;
                position:relative;
                left:50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, 10%);
                text-align: center;
            }

             .div2 {
                font-family: mySecondFont;
                font-size: 3.71em;
                position:relative;
                text-align: center;
                left:50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0px 100px 0px 0px;
            }

            .image {
                position: fixed;
                align-content: space-between;
                top: 35%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;

            }

            body {
                background-image: url('assets/images//bg_rain.png');            
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                background-size:cover;
            }

            .button {
                position: fixed;
                padding-top:40px;
                padding-left: 3000px;
                float:left;
            }


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="index.html"><div class="button">
            <img src="assets/images/buttons/home_rollover_over.gif" onmouseover="this.src='assets/images/buttons/home_rollover_under.gif'"onmouseout="this.src='assets/images/buttons/home_rollover_over.gif'" ></div>
        </a>

        <div class="div1"; style="color:black";style="align: middle">Chapter 1: <br>The Stranger</div>
            <div class="div2"; style="color:black";style="align: middle">Text Text Text</div>
            <div class = "image"; style="align: middle"><img src="assets/images/narrative/man_liferaft.png"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use bootstrap

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ In order to resize elements on your page (either smaller or larger) you will need to implement `@media queries` which restructure the page according to the size of the viewing device _ Here's a link to more information about this subject >>> https://medium.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-web-development/media-queries-54a1a463356f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many mistakes on your code:
- you put `;` to separate html tag attributes, you should put it inside the style attribute instead, to separate the styles
- you don't need `position: relative` just to center the text, you can use `text-align`
- you also don't need the `left: 50%` and `transform: translate()` to center the text, this is a hack when something is difficult to center
- when you using `position` other than relative (absolute and fixed), you don't need `float: right`
- also when using `position`, you can just move it using `top`, `bottom`, `left`, or `right`, don't make the element bigger by padding it, unless if its necessary
- you can't use `justify-content` or `align-items` if you don't use `display: flex`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<head>
    <title>The Impossible Journey</title>

    <link rel="icon" href="assets/images/buttons/website_browser_icon.png">

    <style>

        @font-face{
            font-family:myFirstFont; 
            src: url('assets/fonts/makoa.ttf');

        }

        @font-face{
            font-family:mySecondFont; 
            src: url('assets/fonts/simplicity.otf');
        }

        .div1 {
            font-family: myFirstFont;
            font-size: 10em;
            text-align: center;
            color: black;
        }



        .div2 {
            font-family: mySecondFont;
            font-size: 3.71em;
            text-align: center;
            color: black;
            margin: 0px 100px 0px 0px;
        }

        .image {
            text-align: center;
        }

        body {
            background-image: url('assets/images//bg_rain.png');            
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            background-size:cover;
        }

        .button {
            position: fixed;
            top: 40px;
            right: 40px;
        }


    </style>

    </head>

<body>

<a href="index.html"><div class="button"><img src="assets/images/buttons/home_rollover_over.gif" onmouseover="this.src='assets/images/buttons/home_rollover_under.gif'"onmouseout="this.src='assets/images/buttons/home_rollover_over.gif'" ></div></a>



<div class="div1">Chapter 1: <br> The Stranger</div>

<div class="image"><img src="assets/images/narrative/man_liferaft.png"></div>

<div class="div2">You decide to set a path toward the object.  As you draw closer, you discover it's a man, passsed out on an inflatable life raft.  You tie his life raft to the boat, haul him aboard and wait for him to wake up. <br> Your journey continues.
    </div>





                    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view your image after the paragraph, then you shouldn't be using `position: fixed`. you have to use `position: relative` also to center align the image you can use flex property.

This is how you CSS should look like, you can adjust the margin paddings as you want.

```
         .div1 {
            font-family: myFirstFont;
            font-size: 10em;
            position:relative;
            text-align: center;
        }



         .div2 {
            font-family: mySecondFont;
            font-size: 3.71em;
            position:relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        }

        .image {
            position: relative;
            align-content: space-between;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            display:flex;

        }

        body {
            background-image: url('assets/images//bg_rain.png');            
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            background-size:cover;
            padding:0 15px;
        }

        .button {
            position: fixed;
            padding-top:40px;
            right: 40px;
            float:left;
        }
```